# Откуда произошло слово "дверь"?

Tags: этимология

Откуда произошло слово "дверь"?

Comment: Я думаю, индоевропейское происхождение. Родственное английскому door, немецкому Tür. Также во многих других индоевропейских языках есть родственные слова этому слову.

Comment: @CITBL тогда откуда door? интересуют корни слова.

Comment: И дверь и door и Tür - всё через своих предков восходит к общему праиндоевропейскому языку. А уж откуда оно там взялось - кто знает.

Answer (score 7):

> Общеслав. индоевроп. характера. Того же корня (с перегласовкой), что и двор (1)}}, латышск. dvars «калитка», нем. Tür «дверь», Tor «ворота», лат. foris «двустворчатая дверь» и т. д. Исходное значение — «ворота (двора), двустворчатая дверь»

Из этимологического словаря Крыловой. По Фасмеру – итог такой же. Извините за цитирование.

> ДВЕРЬ
>   ж., двери мн., укр. дверi мн., ст.-слав. двьри мн., двьрь (Мейе, Et. 207, 261), словен. duri мн., ж., стар. davri, чеш. dveri, dvere, польск. drzwi, в.-луж. durje мн., н.-луж. zurja. Другая ступень чередования: двор. Родственно лит. durys, род. п. duru, duriu, вост.-лит. dures, лтш. duris, гот. daur "ворота", д.-в.-н. turi "двери", др.-исл. dyrr, греч. " дверь", (из *dhverios) "дверная петля", лат. fores "двустворчатая дверь", foris ж. "дверь", др.-инд. dvaras "двери" ж., мн. (вин. duras), кимр. dor, алб. dere "дверь"; первонач. основа на согласный (Бернекер 1, 241 и сл.; Траутман, BSW 63; М. – Э. 1, 520 и сл.; Мейе, Et. 176, 261; Брандт, РФВ 22, 113). Об исходном корне-основе см. Бругман, Grdr. 2, 1, 132 и сл

Answer (score -1):

ЭТИМОЛОГИЯ СЛОВА «ДВЕРЬ».
Может быть , все гораздо проще?
Есть корень множества слов – « др (тр ), означающий некое     низкочастотное действие, чаще всего сопровождаемое низкочастотными звуками (др-р-р, тр- р- р): дрожать, трещать, трепещать, трястись, traškėti ( трещать – лит. яз. ) и т. д. И слово  «дыра» того же происхождения – т. е. надо  ударять по чему, или совершать какие – сверлящие действия ,в результате которых появляется отверстие( дыра) . Вероятно, древнпй человек находил уже пробитую в горе дыру( конечно, пробитую богами) и за ней открывалась пещера, в которой можно было спрятаться от непогоды,диких зверей.  Эту дыру он заваливал или камнем, или завешивал какой – нибудь шкурой , и постпенно название «дыра» закрепилось за этим закрывающим дыру предметом. Потом Человек научился делать из камня уже искусственные пещеры- дома, а в северых лесных районах Земли делали полуземлянки, а дыру он закрывалуже щитом , сделанным из дерева, и уже на него перенесли это название – у многих народов, родственным русскому языку, звучало как близкое слову – «дверь» или «дыра»:
Английское door.
Литовское – durys,
Армянское – durr,
Белорусское – dzviery,
Ирландский – doras  и т.п. .

Александр Гущин

Answer (score -1):

Я склонен к версии Александра Гущина, что слово "дверь" происходит от слова "дерево" (также как и слово "деревня"). В обоих словах слово "дерево" как материал (предмет)  являеться исходным. Слово "дверь" в отличии от слова "деревня"  намного древнее. Со временем слово естественно изменилось. К стати слово "древний" тоже происходит от слова "дерево". В подтверждение - к примеру в чеченском языке слово "дверь" это - слово "наь1",которое по мимо значения "дверь" имеет значение слова "шкура". Видимо в древности нахи (чеченцы и ингуши) вход в свои жилиша прикрывали шкурами. Со временем  материал двери изменился, но название осталоcь.
 Vaha Chamelev